# Different output when passing string by props and using a const value

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to pass text to my react component using props. The important thing is I need the new line symbol ("\n") to work.

My example is very simple:

```js
class UnderlinedText extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const text = 'Hello\n this is a test'; // this works
    // const text = this.props.text; this does NOT work
    return (
      <div className="textContainer">{text}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <UnderlinedText />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.textContainer {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Using the hardcoded text above everything works as it should (even in debug I see that the string spans in multiple lines). But using it via props like so:

```js
class UnderlinedText extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const text = this.props.text;
    return (
      <div className="textContainer">{text}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <UnderlinedText text='Hello\n this is a test' />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.textContainer {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

does not create the new lines and the string in debug has all the new line symbols ("\n") in it.

Where is the difference between those two solutions? And how to solve it?

Comment: Well what exactly does `this.props.text` contain?

Comment: the value is: "Hello\n this is a test"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using a literal string in

```
<UnderlinedText text='Hello\n this is a test' />
```

React is treating it as **literal text**. `\n` is `\` and `n`, just like it would be in an HTML attribute.

If you want to supply a JavaScript string with JavaScript escape sequences in it, use `{}` around it to switch to a JavaScript expression context:

```
<UnderlinedText text={'Hello\n this is a test'} />
```

Live Example:

```js
class UnderlinedText extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const text = this.props.text;
    return (
      <div className="textContainer">{text}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <UnderlinedText text={'Hello\n this is a test'} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.textContainer {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works! Thx! Since the solution was soooo easy I feel super stupid now :(

Comment: @L3M0L - No need. :-) There are a lot of layers in this stuff, easy to get caught between them.